# Add/Merge 2 Stages within a single Stage in MS Dynamics (on-premise or online)

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

Is there a way merge/show 2 stages within a bigger stage?

[image]

Some of our business processes have 2 stages within a certain macro-stage and we don't want our sales team to think they are on a separate stage.

If there isn't a point & click customization way, can it be hard coded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no sub-stages in BPF. You can always have a sub-status dropdown on each stage or split them into two different stages.

If you are talking about either the branching or concurrent Processes on the same record, then it's little different. If that's the case, you have to retrieve the other stages/processes & display in web resource for clear picture.

I strongly believe you can fix this by simple user training :)